# UserDefault is not working with M1 Chip MacBook Air and Xcode Simulator in Swift 5

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, swift5, apple-m1, userdefaults

I have M1 chip MacBook Air laptop. I set, remove and get value from UserDefaults.

Below code I set the value

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue("my string", forKey: "UserEmail")
```

Get the value using valueforkey

```
UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserEmail")
```

Remove key from userdefaults using removeObject

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "UserEmail")
```

Even if I set the value through **"UserEmail"**, I am not able to get the value. Strange thing happened if I run four to five times then sometime I got the value and sometime not in the simulator! I have searched on google, stack overflow and already spent so many hours on this issue but not find any solution.

It only worked if I run this on Actual Device and other laptop that doesn't have M1 chip.

Can anyone help me out What should I do so it will work fine in simulator and on my M1 chip laptop.

Comment: Shouldn't be a M1 problem. Make sure you aren't accidentally resetting `UserDefaults` every time on startup.

Comment: No I am not restarting userdefault value.

Comment: It's not reproducible in a playground or simulator for me. Any reason you are not using `UserDefaults.standard.string` when reading the value?

Comment: No there Is not reason for this. I try this way too but not working for me!

Comment: Well the bottom line is that you have not provided enough information to make this reproducible so unless someone has experienced (and solved) the exact same issue I don’t think this  question can be answered.

Comment: I cannot provide my code it's because of privacy. It's true that no one can help me with this details. I will try to solved this. Thank you :-)

Comment: I also has this issue. stopped application and run again its lead to loss of data from userdefault. @YogeshPatel

Answer (score 0):

Try `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`, though it is a deprecated API. On a side note, if it works with this call, there is a bug on Apple and ARM chip side.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are working with a release scheme on your simulator: Edit Scheme -> Run -> Build Configuration that value should be in "Debug" and not in "Release".
Also check the debug executable option.

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason that UserDefaults doesn't work in Release build configuration?

Comment: The UserDefaults is working, what's not working is the debugging. He may be thinking that he can't get the value but it's not a UserDefaults issue, It's a debugger issue.